# How to solve $y''=\frac{1}{y}\left(y'\right)^2+y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't see any possibility for solving $y''=\frac{1}{y}\left(y'\right)^2+y$, so I tried by $p=y'$ but it does not work out properly.

Comment: Please don't make edits that change the question completely.

Comment: Please open a new question for a new topic, do not change existing questions, especially when they already have valid answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation supposes that $y \neq 0$, and you can write it :
\begin{align}
\dfrac{y'' y - (y')^2}{y^2} = 1
\end{align}

Try to find what the left term is the derivative of, then you can compute a solution : it should lead you to a linear first order differential equation of the form $y' = (x+C)y$.

Edit : complete solution :
\begin{align}
1 = \dfrac{y'' y - (y')^2}{y^2} = \left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)'
\end{align}

Thus by integrating : $y'/y = x+c$, and $y$ is solution of $y'=y(x+c)$. The solutions are of the form $y(x) = \lambda e^{\frac{x^2}{2} + cx}$ with $c$ and $\lambda$ constants coefficients.

Comment: Should i do a substitution of p=y'?

Comment: No. Hint : what is the derivative of $\frac{y'}{y}$ ?

Comment: Variation paramterers method is the solution : what is the nasty integral ? If it is of $\cos x e^x$, use the fact that $\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$

Comment: @anon: Please open a new topic for unrelated questions. Also add your own insights so that known facts need not be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Cross multiplying, we get

$$yy''-(y')^2 = y^2$$

Divide both sides $(y')^2$

$$\frac{yy'' - (y')^2}{(y')^2} = \frac{y^2}{(y')^2}$$

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{y}{y'}\right) = \left(\frac{y}{y'}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to find the function $p$ that connects $y$ and $y'$ via $y'=p(y)$.
$$
p'p=\frac{p^2}y-y\implies p'=\frac{p}y-\frac{y}p
$$
This now suggests to try $p=uy$,
$$
yu'+u=u+\frac1u\implies uu'=\frac1y\implies u(y)=\pm\sqrt{2\ln|y|+C}
$$
so that
$$
y'=\pm y\sqrt{2\ln|y|+C}
$$
This now is separable,...